# How can I get all collections of Propel model?

Tags: php, propel

How can I iterate over all Propel object collections, e.g:

```
foreach ($obj->getCollections() as $collectionName)
{
    echo "Object's collection $collectionName has " . count($obj->{"get".$collectionName}) . " items<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the TableMap::getRelations() function.
You will find most everything you need to know about Propel introspection in this article:
http://propelorm.org/cookbook/runtime-introspection.html

PS If you only want to know the number of related objects don't go retrieving all of the records - use the count() query function to just return the count.